# Which angle is estimated by the phase estimation algorithm?

Tags: bloch-sphere, quantum-phase-estimation

Is it $\theta$ or $\varphi$ as usually depicted on the Bloch sphere?  In other words, is it the angle projected on the $xy$-plane or is it the one on a plane that intersects the $z$-axis of the Bloch sphere?  How could I have answered this myself?

[image: bloch sphere]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither.

Phase estimation algorithm does not estimate a property of a qubit state (and the angles $\theta$ and $\varphi$ in your question are exactly that - a property of a given qubit state).

Rather, it estimates the eigenvalue of a given unitary $U$ that corresponds to the given eigenvector $|\psi\rangle$ - the angle $\alpha$ in the following equation:

$$U|\psi\rangle = e^{2i\pi\alpha}|\psi\rangle$$

[Wikipedia article on phase estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_phase_estimation_algorithm) has more details on the algorithm.